# open startup applications preferences on Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, startup, startup-applications

I recently installed Lubuntu 14.04 on a Compaq nc6000 with 768MB of RAM and 80GB hard drive. I want to tweak Lubuntu for faster bootup (because it is slow). I watched a [video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwBoHZuauL8), where the author suggested tweaking it from Startup Applications preferences. I couldn't locate it and I don't know how to "create it". I tried to follow the directions she suggested:

Inputting a command on the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g­" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> for changes to be applied.

but I can't open the startup applications preferences window because I don't know how to do it or create it on Lubuntu 14.04!
She also suggested installing Preload from Software Center.

Answer (score 3):

Startup Applications are found here...

Start Menu → Preferences → Default applications for LXSession →
AutoStart.